# Import and python source file in folders

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have some troubles understanding how python import works.

I just forked [this repository](https://github.com/mariosangiorgio/python-fitbit) and I am going to play with it but i am having troubles understanding how python `import` works with file in directories.

The directory structure is the following:

```
fitbit/
    __init__.py
    gather_keys_cli.py
    api.py
    exceptions.py
    utils.py
```

As a preliminary step I need to run `gather_keys_cli.py`. It depends on `api.py`, which in turn depends on `exceptions.py`.

If I try to run it from the python interpreter everything works as expected. If I try to run it from the command line (As suggested in the [documentation](http://python-fitbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) I have obtain the following exception.

```
$./fitbit/gather_keys_cli.py KEY SECRET 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fitbit/gather_keys_cli.py", line 34, in <module>
    from api import FitbitOauthClient
  File "/Users/mariosangiorgio/FitBitHacks/python-fitbit/fitbit/api.py", line 9, in <module>
from fitbit.exceptions import (BadResponse, DeleteError, HTTPBadRequest,
ImportError: No module named fitbit.exceptions
```

My understanding is that when I invoke the command line the base path is set to the folder containing it. At this point, the scripts correctly imports the oauth client because it uses this instruction `from api import FitbitOauthClient`, which does not contain any reference to the fitbit directory.

On the opposite, `api.py` uses this instruction to import exceptions `from fitbit.exceptions import (LIST_OF_CLASSES)`. This instruction contains the reference to the fitbit directory and hence I got the error.

I am not familiar with python so I'd like to understand what is the pythonic way to solve this issue.
I have the feeling that there is something clearly wrong going on and I found a workaround by moving `gather_keys_cli.py` and changing the api import to `import fitbit.api`. It works but I am not sure it is the right way to solve the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: I am not sure if this solves your problem, but have you tried the following? in gather_keys_cli.py do: `from . import api.py`. And in api.py do `from . import exceptions.py`